# close open position with the help of request.security_lower_tf function

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

//get lower time frame data
barTime = input.time(0, title="Select Bar", confirm = true)
lowerTimeframe = input.timeframe("5", 'Lower Timeframe')

type ohlc
    float o
    float h
    float l
    float c

getOhlc()=>ohlc.new(open, high, low, close)

array<ohlc> ohlcArray = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, lowerTimeframe, getOhlc(), true) 

bgcolor(time == barTime?color.aqua:na)

var int l = na
var int r = na
var float t = na
var float b = na
if(time == barTime)
    lastClose = close[1]
    
    for [i, ohlcValue] in ohlcArray
        left = bar_index-3*(array.size(ohlcArray)-i)
        right = left + 2
        mid = left + 1
        borderColor = ohlcValue.c > lastClose? color.green : color.red
        lastClose := ohlcValue.c
        bgcolor = ohlcValue.c > ohlcValue.o? na: borderColor
        ocMax = math.max(ohlcValue.o, ohlcValue.c)
        ocMin = math.min(ohlcValue.o, ohlcValue.c)
        box.new(left, ocMax, right, ocMin, borderColor, 1, bgcolor=bgcolor)
        line.new(mid, ocMax, mid, ohlcValue.h, color=borderColor)
        line.new(mid, ocMin, mid, ohlcValue.l, color=borderColor)
    leftMost = bar_index-3*(array.size(ohlcArray))
    rightMost = bar_index
    borderColor = close > close[1]? color.green : color.red
    bodyColor = color.new(borderColor, 90)


longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy. Short)
```

currently i am working at 4 hr time frame and i want to exit my long and short entry behalf of 5 min lower time frame and the exit condition is ...(attention please ohlc value should be at 5 min time frame)

```
bool crossover = (close > high[2])
bool crossunder = (close < low[2])

bool closeLongPosition = longDealsEnabled and crossunder
bool closeShortPosition = shortDealsEnabled and crossover
```